# dget complains that public key not found

Tags: debian-squeeze, gpg, patch-management

I'm trying to [backport a package](https://wiki.debian.org/SimpleBackportCreation), but `dget` (`dscverify`) says that it can't check the signature because of public key not being found:

```
[root ~/build/openssl] dget -x http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/o/openssl/openssl_0[72/753]
queeze14.dsc
dget: retrieving http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/o/openssl/openssl_0.9.8o-4squeeze14.dsc
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  2003  100  2003    0     0  27106      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 47690
dget: retrieving http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/o/openssl/openssl_0.9.8o.orig.tar.gz
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 3684k  100 3684k    0     0  3507k      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:-- 3615k
dget: retrieving http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/o/openssl/openssl_0.9.8o-4squeeze14.debia
n.tar.gz
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 94425  100 94425    0     0   371k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  422k
openssl_0.9.8o-4squeeze14.dsc:
dscverify: openssl_0.9.8o-4squeeze14.dsc failed signature check:
gpg: keyblock resource `/root/.gnupg/secring.gpg': file open error
gpg: Signature made Mon 11 Feb 2013 11:04:16 PM EET using RSA key ID 1A5522DD
gpg: Can't check signature: public key not found
Validation FAILED!!
```

I've tried updating `debian-keyring` package, specifying `dsc` files from different versions of `debian`. To no avail. How come it can't verify the signature? Can I ignore this messege? Or what an I to do?

Comment: Stop using lenny? That went out of support years ago.

Comment: It's not `lenny`, it's `squeeze`.

Comment: Do you have the `debian-keyring` package installed?

Comment: Yes, I stated the in the question. But I've confirmed that just now, `dpkg` says `2010.12.29` for version.

Comment: The same goes for `wheeze`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running the following command solves the problem.

```
$ gpg -k
```

As far as I can tell, the problem lies in `gpg` complaining about not being configured. In the end the following command is run:

```
cat openssl_0.9.8o-4squeeze14.dsc | gpg --batch --no-options --no-default-keyring \
    --always-trust --keyring /usr/share/keyrings/debian-keyring.gpg \
    --keyring /usr/share/keyrings/debian-maintainers.gpg
```

**UPD** And here's a [bug report](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=706919).

**UPD** Link to [mailing list discussion](https://lists.debian.org/debian-backports/2014/04/msg00091.html).